# are there any lisp implementations or 3rd party libraries that support dotnet or com interop

Tags: .net, com, lisp

Any lisp environment supporting the following

1. using com objects.

2. acting as a com server...

Comment: There's IronLISP, which has been superseded by IronScheme.

Comment: Allegro com server documentation: http://www.franz.com/support/documentation/current/doc/ole.htm#writing-a-server-2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Allegro Common Lisp](http://www.franz.com/products/allegrocl/acl_connectivity_tools.lhtml) and [IronScheme](http://ironscheme.codeplex.com/) has built-in support for COM. You can get any Common Lisp that runs on Windows to talk to COM components or make it act as a COM server by using [CFFI](http://common-lisp.net/project/cffi/).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it's COM, but Edi's [RDNZL](http://weitz.de/rdnzl/) is "more or less a foreign function interface for .NET languages like C#".

Answer (score 0):

[Racket](http://docs.racket-lang.org/mzcom/index.html) and [newLisp](http://www.newlisp.org/index.cgi?Code_Contributions) are also accessible from com.